# Can I use SQLite.swift's Codable functionality with enums?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite.swift

I'm trying to use SQLite.swift's [`Codable` functionality](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#codable-types) to insert a row, but am getting the following error message:

```
Swift.EncodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Top-level 
MyEnum encoded as number JSON fragment.", underlyingError: nil))
```

My enum extends `Int` and `Codable`:

```
enum MyEnum : Int, Codable {
    case FIRSTVAL = 0, SECONDVAL = 1
}
```

And the class consuming it looks like this:

```
class MyClass : Codable {        
    static let tableRef = Table("MyTable")

    static let idColumn = Expression<Int>("MyTableId");
    static let nameColumn = Expression<String>("Name")
    static let myEnumValColumn = Expression<Int>("MyEnumVal")

    static func createTable(_ db : Connection) throws {            
        try db.run(tableRef.create(ifNotExists: true) { t in
            t.column(idColumn, primaryKey: true)
            t.column(nameColumn)
            t.column(myEnumValColumn)
        })            
    }

    var MyTableId : Int!
    var Name : String
    var MyEnumVal : MyEnum
}
```

The code that attempts to insert the row and causes the error to be thrown:

```
try db.run(MyClass.tableRef.insert(anInstanceOfMyClass))
```

I know in the documentation for SQLite.swift it says:

> The encodable and decodable objects can only use the following types:
>
> - Int, Bool, Float, Double, String
> - Nested Codable types that will be    encoded as JSON to a single column

Is there a way to force it to use the `rawValue` of the enum (as it extends `Int` anyway), perhaps by implementing the encode/decode method manually for either `MyEnum` or `MyClass`? I'm trying to avoid having to manually write code to deserialise the row from the database back into an object and serialise from an object ready for the database. For example I previously had the following methods in `MyClass` (as well as other bits of code that loaded entities from the DB too and had to deserialise them):

```
init(row : Row) {
    self.MyTableId = row[MyClass.idColumn]
    self.Name = row[MyClass.nameColumn]       
    self.MyEnumVal = MyEnum(rawValue: Int(row[MyClass.myEnumValColumn]))!
}

func insert(_ db : Connection) throws {
    let insert = MyClass.tableRef.insert(
        MyClass.idColumn <- Int(MyTableId),
        MyClass.nameColumn <- Name,
        MyClass.myEnumValColumn <- Int(MyEnumVal.rawValue)
    )
    try db.run(insert)
}
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?